# Not getting proper range value when using partial content header

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm trying to playback an mp4 that resides outside my web root. Had no issue there except that I couldn't seek within the video. Research lead me to the http "206 partial content" header.

This is the php that serves the file:

```
    const STORAGE_PATH = '/home/files/';
    
    
    $filename = "my_video.mp4";
    $file = STORAGE_PATH.$filename;
    
    
    $size  = filesize($file);
    $begin  = 0;
    $end  = $size - 1;


header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])){
    
    $range = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], '=')+1);
    $range = explode('-', $range);
    $begin = intval($range[0]);
    $end   = (isset($range[1]) && !empty($range[1])) ? intval($range[1]) : $size-1;
    
    

    $length = $end - $begin + 1;


    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header("Content-Range: bytes $begin-$end/$size");
    
    fseek($f, $begin);
}


$length = ($end - $begin) + 1;

header('Content-Length:' .$length);
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
//header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
//header('Expires: 0');
//header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
//header('Pragma: public');


echo fread($f, $length);
flush();
fclose($f);
exit();
```

When I load the page with the html5 video tag, it fails to load the video with the following console error:
**net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 206 (Partial Content)**

With chrome dev tools, it's showing the requested header is only sending the first range value but not the second.

**Range: bytes=0-**

In response, my script is sending back the entire range of the file since it's not finding a specific range from the server. I'm not sure where the problem is at this point.

Comment: What's the reason for `[\D.*]?` at the end of the regexp? There's nothing after `Range: bytes=start-end` in the request header.

Comment: What Range header is the browser sending?

Comment: So I thought that range had to send two numbers, but if the second number is omitted then assume end of file.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range

Comment: That's right. But why are you matching an optional character after the second number? Also, `.` and `*` are redundant in there, since `\D` matches anything that isn't a digit.

Comment: I updated the code and used a simpler method for retrieving the range values. I believe the problem lies in the data being read

Comment: So add `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);` to see the data being rad.